# SUB TOTAL WITH MULTIPLE TABLE

Tags: sql, xampp

I want to show the subtotals of each product name and maybe the commands I made are useless,
is there any suggestions for me

I have 3 tables

```
select
    ORDERS.ORDER_NUM,
    PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID,
    PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME,
    ORDER_DETAILS.QUANTITY,
    ORDER_DETAILS.UNIT_PRICE,
    sum(ORDER_DETAILS.UNIT_PRICE) as SUBTOTAL
from
    ORDER_DETAILS
    inner join ORDERS on ORDER_DETAILS.ORDER_NUM = ORDERS.ORDER_NUM
    inner join PRODUCT on ORDER_DETAILS.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID
group by
    ORDER_DETAILS.ITEM_NUM
order by
    PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME;
```

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+
| ORDER_NUM | PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT_NAME | QUANTITY | UNIT_PRICE | SUBTOTAL |
+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+
|      3004 |       2001 | BEER         | 10       | 160,000    |      160 |
|      3012 |       2001 | BEER         | 5        | 160,000    |      160 |
|      3002 |       2005 | CAKE         | 5        | 50,000     |       50 |
|      3001 |       2004 | CIGARETTE    | 2        | 25,000     |       25 |
|      3011 |       2004 | CIGARETTE    | 5        | 25,000     |       25 |
|      3005 |       2007 | ICE CREAM    | 50       | 10,000     |       10 |
|      3007 |       2010 | MILK         | 3        | 45,000     |       45 |
|      3010 |       2010 | MILK         | 7        | 12,000     |       12 |
|      3008 |       2008 | NOODLES      | 1        | 5,000      |        5 |
|      3013 |       2006 | SODA         | 50       | 12,000     |       12 |
|      3009 |       2002 | WINE         | 1        | 200,000    |      200 |
|      3003 |       2002 | WINE         | 2        | 200,000    |      200 |
|      3006 |       2002 | WINE         | 1        | 200,000    |      200 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: define subtotal of product? also tag your database and provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Looks like you want a *Group Sum*, most DBMSes support: `sum(ORDER_DETAILS.UNIT_PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID) as SUBTOTAL`  and remove the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the database.  However, you need to fix your query:

- Details from the order and order line are not appropriate, if you are summarizing by product.
- The `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` lists should be consistent.
- The total you want is probably the price times the quantity.

So, the query should be more like this:

```
select p.PRODUCT_ID, p.PRODUCT_NAME,
       sum(od.UNIT_PRICE * od.QUANTITY) as SUBTOTAL
from ORDER_DETAILS od join
     ORDERS o
     on od.ORDER_NUM = o.ORDER_NUM join
     PRODUCT p
     on od.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
group by p.PRODUCT_ID, p.PRODUCT_NAME
order by p.PRODUCT_NAME;
```

Also note the use of table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.